# Progress image upload Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problem with ajax progress bar in FireFox (on Chrome work fine). If i upload photo they immediately reaches 100%.

```
$('.img_upload').on('change', function(e) {
  var file_data = $('.img_upload').prop('files')[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('file', file_data);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/admin/ajax/singleImg.php",
    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',
    xhr: function() {
      var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      if (myXhr.upload) {
        $('.img_upload').parent().fadeOut();
        $('.progress').fadeIn();
        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
      }
      return myXhr;
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#nameImg').val(data);
    }
  });
});
```

This is my function progress in FireFox `Percentage`

```
function progress(e) {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    var max = e.total;
    var current = e.loaded;

    var Percentage = (current * 100) / max;
    console.log(Percentage);
    Percentage = parseInt(Percentage);
    $('.progress').fadeIn();
    $('.sr-only').css('position', 'static').html(Percentage + '%');
    var width = Percentage + '%';
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', width);
    if (Percentage >= 100) {
      $('#firstStep').fadeOut();
      $('#secondStep').fadeIn();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can refer link : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html - the same problem on firefox like in my code

Comment: please show your html code